# AJAX best practice appending HTML with CSS

Tags: html, ajax

I am using AJAX to update content in my website. My index page has only a menu bar and a '#content' div where the dynamic HTML is appended.

The server I am using has no PHP or database features so no JSON is used.
I am downloading HTML pages straight from the server and populating the index. I am unsure what the best way to style the dynamic pages with CSS. Should I link the style sheets to the index page or to each of the content page(s)?

Also is there a need to put    tags in the content pages?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how much CSS you have.
But most likely best solution is to just combine all CSS into one file and then link to it from the index page, the benefit of this is that the browser can cache it, which means it keeps a copy and doesn't have to download it multiple times.

As far as tags in the content page goes, if you need them use them, if you don't need them don't use them.

Comment: I agree. My only concern was that some of my dynamic pages have different color backgrounds/font color but I suppose it would be better to class them and differentiate the classes from within the one style sheet. I've just noticed too that jQuery's .html function strips the html of <head> and <body> tags